# get a null exception with a variable in a list of claims

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the code below where I create a list of claims  and add some values:

```
string email = id_token.GetValue("unique_name").ToString();
string name = id_token.GetValue("given_name").ToString();
DataSet ds; 

List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email)
};

string roles = "select name from Roles_Table";
ds = GetDataSet(roles);

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var row in ds.Tables(0).Rows)
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, row("name")));
}
```

When I want to use it like this:

```
ClaimsPrincipal cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
var email = cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value
```

It says email is null and I don't know why. I also tried :

```
var email =cp.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress").Value;
```

But got the same issue. However, the other values of the list are not null.
Need help please.

Comment: Well, the `List<Claims> ` has probably your Claim but you are searching it in the _ClaimsPrincipal.Current_ How do you set that?

Comment: You are right @Steve. I added the claim to ClaimsPrincipal.Current `cp.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));` and it worked.